# сложить соседние элементы в матрице

Tags: java

Входные данные - строки с цифрами, образующие прямоугольную матрицу, ввод заканчивается по слову "end" (без ковычек). Получить матрицу того же размера, каждый элемент которой равен сумме соседних элементов начальной матрицы `(( i,j) = (i-1, j) + (i+1, j) + (i, j-1) + (i, j+1))`; граничные элементы имеют соседей на противоположной стороне матрицы; в случае с одним рядом или одним столбцом элемент может быть сам себе соседом.

Пример:

input 1:

> 9 5 3
>   0 7 -1
>   -5 2 9
>   end

output 1:

> 3 21 22
>   10 6 19
>   20 16 -1

input 2:

> 1
>   end

output 2:

> 4

Я смог написать следующее:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList < int[] > arr = new ArrayList < > ();
    while (true) {
        String input = in .nextLine();
        if (input.equals("end")) {
            break;
        } else {
            String[] item = input.split(" ");
            int[] itemInteger = new int[item.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                itemInteger[i] = Integer.parseInt(item[i]);
            }
            arr.add(itemInteger);
        }
    }
    int row = arr.size();
    int col = arr.get(0).length;
    int[][] result = new int[row][col];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            if (i - 1 < 0) {
                i = row;
            } else if (i + 1 >= row) {
                i = -1;
            } else if (j - 1 < 0) {
                j = col;
            } else if (j + 1 >= col) {
                j = -1;
            }
            result[i][j] = arr.get(i - 1)[j] + arr.get(i + 1)[j] + arr.get(i)[j - 1] + arr.get(i)[j + 1];
        }
    }
    for (int[] tmp: result) {
        for (int x: tmp) {
            System.out.print(x + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

И вылетаю за пределы массива т.к. значение `i = row` при `i-1 < 0` вставляется в `arr.get(i)[j-1]` и т.п.. Исключения в курсе еще не проходились, код написан исходя из моих знаний, возможно я перемудрил и не вижу какого-то простого решения...

Comment: `значение i = row при i-1<0`, нужно `i = row - 1`

Comment: тогда в подсчете результата будет взят не последний элемент массива, а предпоследний, т.к. (i-1) буде равно (row -1-1) при подсчете.

Comment: row - это не последний элемент массива, row - это индекс, следующий за последним элементом, что и есть вылет за пределы массива. Массив нумеруется с нуля: `9 5 3` - размер массива 3, 9 имеет индекс 0, 5 имеет индекс 1, 3 имеет индекс 2. Соответственно проходя по первой же строке, вы i = 3, а элемента с индексом 3 у вас нет в массиве.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том что i и j часто переопределяются и в строке c result они могут быть переопределены несколько раз. Например i = -1; result[i][j], result[-1][j] получается. Я для решения ввел еще 4 переменных. Вот пример.

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
           int a = i;
           int b = i;
           int c = j;
           int d = j;
           if (i - 1 < 0) {
               a = row;
           }
           if (i + 1 >= row) {
               b = -1;
           }
           if (j - 1 < 0) {
               c = col;
           }
           if (j + 1 >= col) {
               d = -1;
           }
           result[i][j] = arr.get(a - 1)[j] + arr.get(b + 1)[j] + arr.get(i)[c - 1] + arr.get(i)[d + 1];
       }
   }
```

Также можно использовать (i + 1) % row и (j + 1) % col, но это не работает для (i - 1) и (j - 1).

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться взятием остатка:

```
((i-1+row)%row; j) - верхний,
((i+1)%row; j) - нижний,
(i; (j-1+col)%col) - левый,
(i; (j+1)%col) - правый.
```

Суммируете их и получите то что нужно для (i; j)

```
result[i][j] = arr.get((i - 1 + row) % row)[j] + arr.get((i + 1) % row)[j] + arr.get(i)[(j - 1 + col) % col] + arr.get(i)[(j + 1) % col];
```

PS А if-ы убрать